# I am not able to sendKeys to the input element using selenium. Also tried with js

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class=" css-0">
<div class="css-zcohbc-singleValue">General</div>
</div>

<div class="css-0">
<div class="" style="display: inline-block;">
<input autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" id="react-select-3-input" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" type="text" aria-autocomplete="list" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 2px; background: 0px center; border: 0px; font-size: inherit; opacity: 1; outline: 0px; padding: 0px; color: inherit;">

<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 14px; font-family: Roboto, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to sendKeys to the input tag.

```
WebElement elmnt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@aria-autocomplete='list']"));
```

Tried using plain Selinium,

```
elmnt.click();
elmnt.sendKeys("Text");
```

Also tried clicking with JS and sending keys

```
JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScripts("arguments[0].click();",elmnt);
elmnt.sendKeys("Text");
```

Could anyone suggest, What I might be missing??

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you provided enough wait before interacting the element?

Comment: @KunduK , I am not getting error, but it is not able to sendKeys(), even if I have provided static wait.